# How to hide Message extension bot "what can i do?" text

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-language-understanding

I have observed that, in my message extension bot when I open one-to-one chat with bot, at the top of my chat bar it asks "What can i do?". But when I try to click nothing happens.
Is there any way I can hide that text as its miss leading.
I have tried to update the manifest but it seems its related to some settings.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"What can i do" lists out a set of [bot commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/create-a-bot-commands-menu?tabs=dotnet) to get started with using your bot. You could remove it by removing the commands in the "bots" section from your app manifest.

Comment: Not sure if you've seen the comment from OP below: "Below is my bot section from manifest, "bots": [ { "botId": "ID", "supportsFiles": true, "scopes": [ "personal", "team" ] } ]"

Comment: So it might be a bug in the Teams client in fact. I haven't had a chance to replicate yet - all my bots right now are either message extension only, or have one or more commands. Are you sure this popup will not appear, if the commands section is gone?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want the user to be able to interact with the bot at all? If so, do you have any commands in the "commandLists" in your manifest? I actually think this is one of the best features of bots in Teams, if you're creating a normal chat bot, because it gives the user some immediate options, saves them typing, and makes it easier than using LUIS even to check for input.

However, if you don't want *any* interaction with your bot, then you shouldn't have a "bot" section in your manifest at all. For an app with a message extension only, you need *only* the "composeExtensions", and don't actually need the "bot" section at all. In this case, the user won't have any chance to 1-1, but that's fine.

To see this, have a look at a sample manifest file:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/...",
  ...
  "bots": [],  <- leave this empty, it is only if you want you user to CHAT with the bot
  ...
  "composeExtensions": [
   "botId": Here is where your BotId goes, JUST to handle message extension commands
  ]
}
```

Comment: I need that option but the issue is its not clickable and neither it is giving any suggestions

Comment: do you have items commands defined for the bot? I assume you're using App Studio? Inside there you can define the commands you want to show for the user on this menu. Bear in mind, when you define these in App Studio you're defining them per scope. What I mean is, what commands you define for 1-1 WON'T appear in group chat or in a channel

Comment: I'm developing a message extension, and app manifest i have mentioned commands, there is only one command in there as there is only a single search ID

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm talking about the "bot commands" section, not the "composeExtensions" (i.e. message extensions) command section - there are sections for both, separately, in the schema - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema

Comment: my bot commands section is as follows:   "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "botID",
      "supportsFiles": true,
      "scopes": [
        "personal",
        "team"
      ]
    }
  ],

Comment: So just to confirm again, do you need the user to ever interact with the bot itself, ASIDE from the message extension?

Comment: yes, we want user to interact with bot with message extension

Comment: This is actually quite confusing - there are TWO places in this manifest to put a bot. ONE of these is for the composeExtension, like this: '{.."composeExtensions": [{ "botId": ...}]..}'. The OTHER PLACE is much earlier, for a -bot you want the use to chat with-. In your case, if you don't ever need 1-1, you ONLY need to put the bot id into the composeExtension, you DON'T need to have an the actual "bot" section filled in in your manifest. I'll update the answer above, where there's more space, will hopefully be more clear.

Comment: I want 1-1 chat feature of the bot and just want to remove that "What can i do" text above the chat bar

Comment: ok, thanks for clarifying. In that case of course you need the bot section as well.

Comment: So can't we remove the text which i have highlighted in the question, as its not clickable so its misleading

Comment: can you please provide your comments

Comment: I thought you'd solved this already. Have you confirmed in your manifest that you have no commands set in the "Bot" section?

Comment: As i told at the start only i want commands in Bot section as i want user to interact with bot directly other than message extension, so i can't remove "Bot" section

Comment: I didn't say remove "bot section", I said remove "commands" section -inside- "bots" section...

Comment: Ya got your point, but i dont have commands rather i have commands in "composeExtensions" section

Comment: Below is my bot section from manifest,   "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "ID",
      "supportsFiles": true,
      "scopes": [
        "personal",
        "team"
      ]
    }
  ]

Comment: Can you please comment